# "You have exceeded the quota for AWS Amplify apps" error while building app in AWS console even if the app limits not breached

Tags: aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KD5e.png)

Tried from console instead of browser still same error

Comment: How many apps do you have? Why do you expect the browser to behave differently? What is the limit currently in place?

Comment: I have only 6 apps there and limit is 25

Comment: I'm getting the same error with 1 app in the region.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I too am getting the same error on only one region: ap-south-1